# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 23, 23, 1) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror, logits

am new to ML so i don't really know what am doing i don't know what logits means in the code i haven't even written logits  i just followed a YouTube tutorial to get my self familiar with the environment.. this is the entire code thanks for your help.. i am aware that there is already this kind of post on stackoverflow but i don't think it applies to my situation maybe it does i don't know but i still don't know how to implement it even if it does so please help me out here am struggling :) tnx
the code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np 
    
img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/data/train/ha/2.jpg").shape
print(img)
imgg = image.load_img("/content/drive/MyDrive/data/train/ha/2.jpg")
plt.imshow(imgg)
train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/data/train/", target_size = (100,100),
    batch_size = 3,
    class_mode ="binary")
    print(train_dataset.class_indices)
    
validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/data/validate/", 
    target_size = (100,100), 
    batch_size = 3, 
    class_mode ="binary")
    
    
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation = 'relu',input_shape =(200,200,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(134,activation = 'relu'),
    ##
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid')
    ])
    
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001),
    metrics =['accuracy'])
    
    model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch = 3,
    epochs = 1,
    validation_data = validation_dataset)
```

the error:

```
2021-01-01 13:39:18.588397: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
(51, 51, 3)
Found 9 images belonging to 2 classes.
{'ha': 0, 'hu': 1}
Found 4 images belonging to 2 classes.
2021-01-01 13:39:22.999078: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-01 13:39:23.026197: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-01-01 13:39:23.092853: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:328] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2021-01-01 13:39:23.092917: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (6e4fde799083): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-01-01 13:39:23.093374: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-01 13:39:23.846859: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-01-01 13:39:23.850373: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2300000000 Hz

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/main.py", line 48, in <module>
    validation_data = validation_dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 726, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3206, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:203 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:152 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:256 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1608 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4979 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:174 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        (logits.get_shape(), labels.get_shape()))

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 23, 23, 1) vs (None, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the input to the dense layer has to be a vector. To achieve that

```
you can
replace tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)
with  tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()
```

or just add

```
tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D() after tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)
```

Comment: Gerry P i think this fixed it thank you very much...  i don't wanna be that guy but i got another error if it doesn't have anything to do with this you don't have to answer it :)   ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 16)